# Cslider.js How to random slide order

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, fadein, fadeout

I have Cslider.js and want the first slide to come up the same each time, however the slides after that I would want them to come up in random order, I have looked on Stackflow, and although there is some similar, I can not get it to work for me, any help greatly appreciated, here is what I have

JS

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

/*
 * Slider object.
 */
$.Slider                = function( options, element ) {

    this.$el    = $( element );

    this._init( options );

};

$.Slider.defaults       = {
    current     : 0,    // index of current slide
    bgincrement : 80,   // increment the bg position (parallax effect) when sliding
    autoplay    : true,// slideshow on / off
    interval    : 5000  // time between transitions
};

$.Slider.prototype  = {
    _init               : function( options ) {

        this.options        = $.extend( true, {}, $.Slider.defaults, options );

        this.$slides        = this.$el.children('div.da-slide');
        this.slidesCount    = this.$slides.length;

        this.current        = this.options.current;

        if( this.current < 0 || this.current >= this.slidesCount ) {

            this.current    = 0;

        }

        this.$slides.eq( this.current ).addClass( 'da-slide-current' );

        var $navigation     = $( '<nav class="da-dots"/>' );
        for( var i = 0; i < this.slidesCount; ++i ) {

            $navigation.append( '<span/>' );

        }
        $navigation.appendTo( this.$el );

        this.$pages         = this.$el.find('nav.da-dots > span');
        this.$navNext       = this.$el.find('span.da-arrows-next');
        this.$navPrev       = this.$el.find('span.da-arrows-prev');

        this.isAnimating    = false;

        this.bgpositer      = 0;

        this.cssAnimations  = Modernizr.cssanimations;
        this.cssTransitions = Modernizr.csstransitions;

        if( !this.cssAnimations || !this.cssAnimations ) {

            this.$el.addClass( 'da-slider-fb' );

        }

        this._updatePage();

        // load the events
        this._loadEvents();

        // slideshow
        if( this.options.autoplay ) {

            this._startSlideshow();

        }

    },
    _navigate           : function( page, dir ) {

        var $current    = this.$slides.eq( this.current ), $next, _self = this;

        if( this.current === page || this.isAnimating ) return false;

        this.isAnimating    = true;

        // check dir
        var classTo, classFrom, d;

        if( !dir ) {

            ( page > this.current ) ? d = 'next' : d = 'prev';

        }
        else {

            d = dir;

        }

        if( this.cssAnimations && this.cssAnimations ) {

            if( d === 'next' ) {

                classTo     = 'da-slide-toleft';
                classFrom   = 'da-slide-fromright';
                ++this.bgpositer;

            }
            else {

                classTo     = 'da-slide-toright';
                classFrom   = 'da-slide-fromleft';
                --this.bgpositer;

            }

            this.$el.css( 'background-position' , this.bgpositer * this.options.bgincrement + '% 0%' );

        }

        this.current    = page;

        $next           = this.$slides.eq( this.current );

        if( this.cssAnimations && this.cssAnimations ) {

            var rmClasses   = 'da-slide-toleft da-slide-toright da-slide-fromleft da-slide-fromright';
            $current.removeClass( rmClasses );
            $next.removeClass( rmClasses );

            $current.addClass( classTo );
            $next.addClass( classFrom );

            $current.removeClass( 'da-slide-current' );
            $next.addClass( 'da-slide-current' );

        }

        // fallback
        if( !this.cssAnimations || !this.cssAnimations ) {

            $next.css( 'left', ( d === 'next' ) ? '100%' : '-100%' ).stop().animate( {
                left : '0%'
            }, 1000, function() { 
                _self.isAnimating = false; 
            });

            $current.stop().animate( {
                left : ( d === 'next' ) ? '-100%' : '100%'
            }, 1000, function() { 
                $current.removeClass( 'da-slide-current' ); 
            });

        }

        this._updatePage();

    },
    _updatePage         : function() {

        this.$pages.removeClass( 'da-dots-current' );
        this.$pages.eq( this.current ).addClass( 'da-dots-current' );

    },
    _startSlideshow     : function() {

        var _self   = this;

        this.slideshow  = setTimeout( function() {

            var page = ( _self.current < _self.slidesCount - 1 ) ? page = _self.current + 1 : page = 0;
            _self._navigate( page, 'next' );

            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                _self._startSlideshow();

            }

        }, this.options.interval );

    },
    page                : function( idx ) {

        if( idx >= this.slidesCount || idx < 0 ) {

            return false;

        }

        if( this.options.autoplay ) {

            clearTimeout( this.slideshow );
            this.options.autoplay   = false;

        }

        this._navigate( idx );

    },
    _loadEvents         : function() {

        var _self = this;

        this.$pages.on( 'click.cslider', function( event ) {

            _self.page( $(this).index() );
            return false;

        });

        this.$navNext.on( 'click.cslider', function( event ) {

            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
                _self.options.autoplay  = false;

            }

            var page = ( _self.current < _self.slidesCount - 1 ) ? page = _self.current + 1 : page = 0;
            _self._navigate( page, 'next' );
            return false;

        });

        this.$navPrev.on( 'click.cslider', function( event ) {

            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
                _self.options.autoplay  = false;

            }

            var page = ( _self.current > 0 ) ? page = _self.current - 1 : page = _self.slidesCount - 1;
            _self._navigate( page, 'prev' );
            return false;

        });

        if( this.cssTransitions ) {

            if( !this.options.bgincrement ) {

                this.$el.on( 'webkitAnimationEnd.cslider animationend.cslider OAnimationEnd.cslider', function( event ) {

                    if( event.originalEvent.animationName === 'toRightAnim4' || event.originalEvent.animationName === 'toLeftAnim4' ) {

                        _self.isAnimating   = false;

                    }   

                });

            }
            else {

                this.$el.on( 'webkitTransitionEnd.cslider transitionend.cslider OTransitionEnd.cslider', function( event ) {

                    if( event.target.id === _self.$el.attr( 'id' ) )
                        _self.isAnimating   = false;

                });

            }

        }

    }
};

var logError            = function( message ) {
    if ( this.console ) {
        console.error( message );
    }
};

$.fn.cslider            = function( options ) {

    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

        this.each(function() {

            var instance = $.data( this, 'cslider' );

            if ( !instance ) {
                logError( "cannot call methods on cslider prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;
            }

            if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for cslider instance" );
                return;
            }

            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );

        });

    } 
    else {

        this.each(function() {

            var instance = $.data( this, 'cslider' );
            if ( !instance ) {
                $.data( this, 'cslider', new $.Slider( options, this ) );
            }
        });

    }

    return this;

};

})( jQuery );
```

This is what I have for HTML

```
 <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2>Dog with a bone</h2>
                <p>place copy here<br />
                Dwell Time</p>
                <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>
                <div class="da-img"><img src="images/1.png" alt="image01" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2>Easy management</h2>
                <p>place copy here</p>
                <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>
                <div class="da-img"><img src="images/2.png" alt="image01" /></div>
            </div>
            <nav class="da-arrows">
                <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
            </nav>
            </div>
```

I have looked on Stackflow and although there are a few, the code is different, and have tried to do this, but i am stumped, Any help greatly apperciated.

Sam